# Credit Card Scanner

Tags: ios, xcode, ocr, photo, scanning

I want to implement a credit card scanner in my application. I have come across https://www.card.io/ and it is exactly the sort of thing I was looking for, but it is not free. Also, I would like not to communicate the information with a remote server.
Do you know any open-source library that can scan a credit card and extract the card number and expiration date from the photo?

Comment: I think that he only want to scan the card, not perform transaction.

Comment: Not nice giving bad rep if you don't understand the question. I don't want to charge the user. I have an application that allows to user to add a card so he can receive bonuses on it. I want to spare him from typeing the number and exp date and allow him to take a photo of his own card. Don't know how you got the idea I was going to charge him. Please read all the question and ask you have any questions before giving bad rep in the future, ok?

Comment: I'm refactoring my project using OpenCV and Tesseract. In a while I'll push it on github and share with everyone, so you can see a possible solution.

Comment: This is the repository https://github.com/pablosproject/iPhone-OCR-Tesseract-and-OpenCV. Enjoy!

Answer (score 3):

You can use the *OpenCV* library for computer vision to process the image and "isolate" the part of the image where there're the numbers. After that you can use *Tesseract*, a good OCR engine mantained by Google to "read" the number from the image; both the libraries are open source.

Exists precompiled version of both the libraries that you can easily include in a Xcode project as static libraries.